# Error when trying to use Flutter to send data to an API server

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-desktop

I get the following error when using Flutter to send a POST request to an API Server.

> The method 'add' isn't defined for the type 'FormData'.
>   (undefined_method at [next_hour] lib\ui\edit_profile.dart:122)

```
    FormData formdata = new FormData();

    Future <String> updateProfile() async{
    newDob  = DateFormat("y-MM-dd").format(_dateTime);
    newMobile=_editMobileController.text;
    print("dek: $newMobile");
    newName=_editNameController.text;
    String imagefileName = tmpFile != null ? tmpFile.path.split('/').last: '';
    try{
      if(imagefileName != ''){
        formdata.add(
            "image", new UploadFileInfo(tmpFile, imagefileName)
        );
      }
      formdata.add(
          "email", sEmail
      );
      formdata.add(
          "current_password", sPass
      );
      formdata.add(
          "new_password", sPass
      );
      formdata.add(
          "dob", newDob
      );
      formdata.add(
          "mobile", newMobile
      );
      formdata.add(
          "name", newName
      );

      await dio.post(APIData.userProfileUpdate, data: formdata, options: Options(
          method: 'POST',

          headers: {
            // ignore: deprecated_member_use
            HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION: fullData,
          }
      )).then(
              (response) {
            setState(() {
              isShowIndicator = false;
            });
            _profileUpdated(context);
          }
      )
          .catchError((error) => print(error.toString()));

    }
    catch(e){
      setState(() {
        isShowIndicator = false;
      });
      print(e);
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: I have edited your question to explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: did you found solution

Answer (score -1):

It looks like add is no longer available in the latest versions of dio, what you can do is the following:

```
FormData.fromMap(<String, dynamic>{ 
"image": new UploadFileInfo(tmpFile, imagefileName),
"mobile" : newMobile, }); 
...
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to make sure about ur function add from

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).